# Rails: Redirecting to post after comment submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form to submit comments on posts.
After submitting comments, the user should be redirected to the post.

I am getting the following error when I hit the "submit" button:

> NameError in CommentsController#create undefined local variable or method `post' for  CommentsController...

The error points to the following line in my comments controller:

```
redirect_to post_path(@post)
```

Here's my `comments_controller.rb`:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

before_action :authenticate_user!

def create
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
  @post = @topic.posts.find(params[:post_id])

  @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
  @comment.post = @post

  redirect_to post_path(@post)
end

private

def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:title, :body)
  end
end
```

And here's my route file:

```
Rclone::Application.routes.draw do
  get "comments/create"
  devise_for :users
  resources :users, only: [:update]

  resources :topics do
    resources :posts, except: [:index] do
      resources :comments, only: [:create]
    end
  end

  get '/posts/:id/comments', to: 'posts#show'

  get 'about' => 'welcome#about'

  root to: 'welcome#index'
end
```

What am I doing wrong on the routes file?

Comment: Did you check, what you get in @post

Answer (score 1):

`Comment.new` will not presist or create the post. You need to do `@comment.save`. Also use `pry` and `pry-nav` gem to debug such errors. `pry` will halt the execution of you program where it finds `binding.pry`. From that point onwards you can execute your program line by line. Just insert `binding.pry` one line before where you want to halt execution.

example

```
def create
  binding.pry
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
```

Check you params hash and you will find your bug. My guess is you are going wrong with `topic_id` or `post_id`

Links:
http://pryrepl.org/
https://github.com/pry/pry